# Current AndroidStudio sample fails on phone due to runtime native library link error. Why?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Its on an HTC Aria, running 2.2 (API 8)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Aria
The aria is an armv6 device that supports opengles 2

If you open up the latest Android Studio (im working on windows 7), then import the HelloGL2 sample, then simply try to run it on the above device, it will fail as soon as it tries to make a call into the native library.

Here is the log:

```
01-06 11:14:08.467 12771-12813/com.android.gl2jni D/dalvikvm: Trying to load    lib /data/data/com.android.gl2jni/lib/libgl2jni.so 0x44c165d0
01-06 11:14:08.467 12771-12813/com.android.gl2jni I/dalvikvm: Unable to dlopen(/data/data/com.android.gl2jni/lib/libgl2jni.so): Cannot load library: link_image[1995]: failed to link libgl2jni.so
01-06 11:14:08.477 12771-12813/com.android.gl2jni W/dalvikvm: Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown during Lcom/android/gl2jni/GL2JNILib;.<clinit>
01-06 11:14:08.497 12771-12813/com.android.gl2jni W/dalvikvm: threadid=8: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40028a00)
01-06 11:14:08.517 95-121/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed activity com.android.gl2jni/.GL2JNIActivity: 9823 ms (total 2027818 ms)
01-06 11:14:08.567 12771-12813/com.android.gl2jni E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 9
                                                                    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                                        at com.android.gl2jni.GL2JNIView$Renderer.onSurfaceChanged(GL2JNIView.java:332)
                                                                        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1327)
                                                                        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library gl2jni not found
                                                                        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:461)
                                                                        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
                                                                        at com.android.gl2jni.GL2JNILib.<clinit>(GL2JNILib.java:24)
                                                                        at com.android.gl2jni.GL2JNIView$Renderer.onSurfaceChanged(GL2JNIView.java:332) 
                                                                        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1327) 
                                                                        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118) 
01-06 11:14:08.607 95-164/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.gl2jni/.GL2JNIActivity
```

This sample works on the 3 other devices i've tried (Galaxy s5, Galaxy J1, Nexus s)

The line: 'Unable to dlopen(/data/data/com.android.gl2jni/lib/libgl2jni.so): Cannot load library: link_image[1995]: failed to link libgl2jni.so' is probably key. I tried loading the library explicitly using system.loadlibrary, but the same problem happens on that call.

I think it might be something to do with the processor being armv6?
The sample is configured to do  'armeabi' though.

Comment: It's likely because it doesn't support openGLES 2.0 which was introduced fully in API 9.

Comment: Usually this error means your Library (libgl2jni.so) is trying to link to some other shared library internally, and that other shared library is not present on the device, throwing the link error. Use arm-linux-androideabi-readelf.exe  -d /data/data/com.android.gl2jni/lib/libgl2jni.so to find out if there are dependencies. That library might well be openGLES 2.0.